# Overloading subscript operator in arrays by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

I have a question about overloading subscript operators by reference, as shown in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

class NewArray
{
    public:
        typedef array<int, 1024> array_type;
        typedef int&             reference;
        reference operator[](const int i) {
            return array_[i];
        }
    private:
        array_type array_;
};

int main(){

    NewArray lhs, rhs;
    rhs[10] = 1000; // Assigning value to rhs[10]
    lhs[10] = rhs[10]; // Arrays references are the same
    rhs[10] = 0; // Modifying reference

    cout << lhs[10] << " " << rhs[10] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Given that I'm returning references to the array position, and the lhs[10] and rhs[10] references are equal, shouldn't the output be

```
0 0
```

instead of

```
1000 0
```

?

Comment: There are two `NewArray` objects, each with its own `std::array`.

Comment: *"lhs[10] and rhs[10] references are equal"* They are not. `lhs[10]` and `rhs[10];` are two separate integers, and `lhs[10] = rhs[10];` merely copies a value from one to another.

Comment: how does compiler know that `lhs[10] = rhs[10]` needs to make a copy, instead of just assigning the reference?

Comment: @YuHao A reference can only be initialized, never assigned. Any attempts to assign after initialization MUST be an attempt to assign to the referenced value. Note this means you can never "repoint" a reference.

Comment: If the arrays were public, this would be equivalent to `lhs.array_[10] = rhs.array_[10];`.

Comment: @YuHao `lhs.array_[10]` is a regular `int`, not a reference. You can't somehow make it refer to some other integer elsewhere.

Comment: Oh... I understand now. Differently from pointers, references can't be re-assigned.

Comment: A good way to think about references is as an additional name for an existing object.